# Exception calling "GetMessage" with "0" argument(s): "An item with the same key has already been added."

Tags: c#, powershell

I am new with PowerShell, trying to run inline C# code in PowerShell console. But start getting error after some successful runs.
Here is my PowerShell script:

```
$Source = @"
namespace TestNamespace
{
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static string GetMessage()
        {
            return "Text from C#";
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp

[TestNamespace.MyClass]::GetMessage()
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Exception calling "GetMessage" with "0" argument(s): "An item with the same key has already been added."
```

It runs successfully 2/3 times, but after that it start showing this error, even I tried to close PowerShell console and re-open. Can anybody help me out, What could be wrong with this script/scenario.

One thing, might be of interest, this is the original script which was working. Then I changed the return type of GetMessage() method from 'string' to 'void', and then the problem started. Now even this original script is not working, showing same error message.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using the posted code. Maybe there's something else in your script that causes the error.